# Need to left align button in outlook email - mobile view

Tags: html, css, email, outlook, html-email

This is the code I am using for a button that needs to be left-aligned. It is left-aligned in all clients except for Outlook mobile.

```html
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"><meta name="x-apple-disable-message-reformatting"><meta name="color-scheme" content="light dark"><meta name="supported-color-schemes" content="light dark"><!--[if !mso]><!--><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"><!--<![endif]--><title>%%=v(@preheader)=%%</title><!--[if mso]>
  <style type="text/css">
    table {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;margin:0;}
    div, td {padding:0;}
    div {margin:0 !important;}
    sup {font-size: 100% !important;}
  </style>
  <noscript>
    <xml>
      <o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
        <o:PixelsPerInch>96</o:PixelsPerInch>
    </xml>
  </noscript>
<![endif]--><!--[if gte mso 15]>
  <style type="text/css" media="all">
    /* Outlook 2013 Height Fix */
    table, tr, td {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0; }
a{ text-decoration: none !important;}
.em_hide_desktop {
                    display: none !important;
}
  </style>
<![endif]-->
<style type="text/css" >/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
      v2.0 | 20110126
      License: none (public domain)
      */
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details, embed, figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary, time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
.pcr {font-size:16px !important; line-height:24px !important; color:#333333; font-family:'PT Sans', 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif, Helvetica, 'Arial', sans-serif;font-weight: normal;margin:0px 0px 15px 0px !important; }
  t {font-size:16px !important; line-height:24px !important; color:#333333; font-family:'PT Sans', 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif, Helvetica, 'Arial', sans-serif;font-weight: normal;margin:0px 0px 15px 0px !important; }
.em_hide_desktop {
                    display: none !important;
}



ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after, q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}</style>
 <style type="text/css" >/* CLIENT-SPECIFIC STYLES */
img {
    -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
}
/* Force IE to smoothly render resized images. */
#outlook a {
    padding: 0;
}
/* Remove spacing between tables in Outlook 2007 and up. */
.ReadMsgBody {
    width: 100%;
}
.ExternalClass {
    width: 100%;
}
/* Force Outlook.com to display emails at full width. */
p, a, td {
    mso-line-height-rule: exactly;
}
/* Force Outlook to render line heights as they're originally set. */
p, a, td, body, table {
    -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}
/* Prevent Windows- and Webkit-based mobile platforms from changing declared text sizes. */
.ExternalClass, .ExternalClass p, .ExternalClass td, .ExternalClass div, .ExternalClass span, .ExternalClass font {
    line-height: 100%;
}
#MessageViewBody a {
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: inherit;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-weight: inherit;
    line-height: inherit;
}
/* Force Outlook.com to display line heights normally. */
a[x-apple-data-detectors] {
    color: inherit !important;
    text-decoration: none !important;
    font-size: inherit !important;
    font-family: inherit !important;
    font-weight: inherit !important;
    line-height: inherit !important;
}
span.MsoHyperlink {
    mso-style-priority: 99;
    color: inherit;
}
span.MsoHyperlinkFollowed {
    mso-style-priority: 99;
    color: inherit;
}</style>
 <style type="text/css" >@media screen and (max-width: 460px) {
.deviceWidth {
    width: 100%!important;
    min-width: 100%!important;
}
.em_main_table {
    width: 100% !important;
}
.em_wrapper {
    width: 100% !important;
}
  
.center {
    text-align: center !important;
    display: block !important;
}
.right {
    text-align: right !important;
    padding-right:20px;
}
.em_hide_desktop {
                    display: block !important;
}
.em_hide {
                    display: none !important;
}
}</style>
 <style type="text/css" >@media screen and (max-width: 350px) {
.three-col .column {
    max-width: 100% !important;
}
.two-col .column {
    max-width: 100% !important;
}
}

@media screen and (min-width: 351px) and (max-width: 460px) {
/* .three-col .column {
    max-width: 50% !important;
}
.three-col .column, .column1 {
    max-width: 100% !important;
    display: block !important;
} */
.five-col .column {
    max-width: 20% !important;
}
.six-col .column {
    max-width: 16% !important;
}
 
#em_hide_desktop {
                    display: block !important;
}
#em_hide {
                    display: none !important;
}
}

@media screen and (min-width: 461px) {
.three-col .column {
    max-width: 30% !important;
}
.three-col .column1 {
    max-width: 20% !important;
}
.two-col .column {
    max-width: 50% !important;
}
.five-col .column {
    max-width: 20% !important;
}
.sidebar .small {
    max-width: 16% !important;
}
.sidebar .large {
    max-width: 84% !important;
}
 
#em_hide_desktop {
                    display: block !important;
}
#em_hide {
                    display: none !important;
}
}

@media screen and (max-width: 550px) {
.three-col .column, .column1 {
    max-width: 100% !important;
    display: block !important;
}
.two-col .column, .two-col img {
    max-width: 100% !important;
    display: block !important;
}
.five-col .column {
    max-width: 33.3% !important;
}
.sidebar .small {
    max-width: 100% !important;
}
.sidebar .large {
    max-width: 100% !important;
}
 
#em_hide_desktop {
                    display: block !important;
}
#em_hide {
                    display: none !important;
}
}</style>
 <style type="text/css" >@font-face {
    font-family: 'PT Sans';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/ptsans/v12/jizaRExUiTo99u79D0-ExcOPIDUg-g.woff2) format('woff2');
unicode-range: U+0460-052F, U+1C80-1C88, U+20B4, U+2DE0-2DFF, U+A640-A69F, U+FE2E-FE2F;
}</style>
 <style type="text/css" >@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
.dark-img {
    display: block !important;
    width: auto !important;
    overflow: visible !important;
    float: none !important;
    max-height: inherit !important;
    max-width: inherit !important;
    line-height: auto !important;
    margin-top: 0px !important;
    visibility: inherit !important;
}
.light-img {
    display: none !important;
}
.link-arrow-lm {
    display: none !important;
}
.link-arrow-dm {
    display: inline !important;
}
.darkmode {
    background-color: #161615 !important;
}
.darkmode-light-bg {
    background-color: #ffffff !important;
}
h1, h2, h3, h4 {
    color: #4F5948 !important;
}
h3, h4 {
    color: #c7102d !important;
}
h3, h4 {
    color: #c7102d !important;
}
p {
    color: #4F5948 !important;
}
a {
    color: #ffffff !important;
}
.light {
    color: #ffffff !important;
}
.dark {
    color: #4F5948 !important;
}
.blue {
    color: #005B9E !important;
}
.orange {
    color: #FF6000 !important;
}
[data-ogsc] .dark-img {
    display: block !important;
    width: auto !important;
    overflow: visible !important;
    float: none !important;
    max-height: inherit !important;
    max-width: inherit !important;
    line-height: auto !important;
    margin-top: 0px !important;
    visibility: inherit !important;
}
[data-ogsc] .light-img {
    display: none !important;
}
[data-ogsc] .link-arrow-lm {
    display: none !important;
}
[data-ogsc] .link-arrow-dm {
    display: inline !important;
}
[data-ogsc] .darkmode {
    background-color: #161615 !important;
}
[data-ogsc] .darkmode-light-bg {
    background-color: #ffffff !important;
}
[data-ogsc] h1, [data-ogsc] h2 {
    color: #4F5948 !important;
}
[data-ogsc] h3, [data-ogsc] h4 {
    color: #c7102d !important;
}
[data-ogsc] p {
    color: #4F5948 !important;
}
[data-ogsc] a {
    color: #ffffff !important;
}
[data-ogsc] .light {
    color: #ffffff !important;
}
[data-ogsc] .dark {
    color: #4F5948 !important;
}
[data-ogsc] .blue {
    color: #005B9E !important;
}
[data-ogsc] .orange {
    color: #FF6000 !important;
}
}</style>
</head>
<body>

<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="border-collapse: collapse; padding: 0; margin: 0; width:100%;" width="100%">
          <tbody>
           <tr>
            <td align="left" style="border-top:3px solid #FF6000;"><a alias="Hero image" href="%%MBPDEEPLINKCHOOSEYOURSEATS%%?utm_source=mc-transactional&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=bcn-destination-upsell&utm_content=select-room-img&utm_term=en&ajs_event=Email%20Link%20Clicked&ajs_uid=%%SubscriberKey%%" style="text-decoration:none; color:#ffffff; font-family:'PT Sans','Lucida Grande', Helvetica, Arial,sans-serif; font-size: 14px; line-height: 26px; font-weight: normal; text-align:center;" target="_blank"><img alt="Two women entering a hotel room" border="0" src="https://assets.sunwingtravelgroup.com/image/upload/v1641915021/sunwing-prod/Email/Sunwing/BCN/images/SelectRoom_02.png" style="border: 0; display: block; font-family:'PT Sans','Lucida Grande', Helvetica, Arial,sans-serif; font-size: 14px; height: auto; max-width: 600px; outline: 0; padding: 0; width: 100%; display: block;" width="660"></a></td>
           </tr>
          </tbody>
         </table>

         <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="border-collapse: collapse; padding: 0; margin: 0; width:100%;" width="100%">
          <tbody>
           <tr>
            <td align="left" style="padding: 0 26px;">
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="border-collapse: collapse; padding: 0; margin: 0; width:100%;" width="100%">
             <tbody>
              <tr>
               <td align="left" style="padding: 20px 0 10px;">
               <p class="light" style="color:#595959; font-family:'PT Sans','Lucida Grande', Helvetica, Arial,sans-serif; font-weight:bold; font-size:25px; line-height:30px; margin:0;"><span style="font-weight: bold;">Pick the perfect spot</span></p>
               </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
               <td align="left" style="padding: 5px 0 0;">
               <p class="light" style="color:#595959; font-family:'PT Sans','Lucida Grande', Helvetica, Arial,sans-serif; font-weight:normal; font-size:14px; line-height:20px; margin:0;">
Want to be closest to the beach or steps from the pool? Choose your room location prior to arrival.
</p>
               </td>
              </tr>
             <tr>
               <td align="left"  style="padding: 30px 0;align:left !important"><!-- CTA BUTTON -->
               <table align="left" bgcolor="#005B9E" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="border: none; border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; margin: auto; mso-table-lspace: 0; mso-table-rspace: 0; background-color:#005B9E; min-width: 180px;">
                <tbody>
                 <tr>
                  <td align="left" style="border-collapse:collapse; font-family:'PT Sans','Lucida Grande', Helvetica, Arial,sans-serif; font-size: 14px; line-height: 18px; font-weight: normal; padding:0; border: 0; text-align:center; color:#ffffff; mso-padding-alt:12px 26px; vertical-align: middle;"><a alias="Start planning-CTA" class="light" href="%%MBPDEEPLINKVACATIONCHECKLIST%%?utm_source=mc-transactional&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=bcn-destination-upsell&utm_content=select-room-cta&utm_term=en" style="text-decoration:none; color:#ffffff; font-family:'PT Sans','Lucida Grande', Helvetica, Arial,sans-serif; font-size: 14px; line-height: 26px; font-weight: normal; text-align:center;" target="_blank"><!--[if !gte mso 9]><!----><span style="padding:12px 26px; display:block;align:left"><!--<![endif]-->Select your room <!--[if !gte mso 9]><!----> </span><!--<![endif]--> </a></td>
                 </tr>
                </tbody>
               </table>
               </td>
               <!-- /CTA BUTTON -->
              </tr>
             </tbody>
            </table>
            </td>
           </tr>
          </tbody>
         </table>


</body>
</html>
```

Any suggestions would be helpful. Stackoverflow just doesn't let me post saying please add more details so not sure what else to add and just typing to see if the error goes away so that I can post.

Comment: Please post the css

Comment: @RohitGupta I have added the CSS to the question. It would be great if you see the issue.

Comment: There is not enough html there to reproduce the problem

Comment: @RohitGupta I added the entire block of code. With a header and footer this would be an email. I hope this is enough to find the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done the following. Let me now if it works for you.

- added a class of CTA to the table that contains the CTA,
- removed align from the table
- removed margin: auto from the table
- class CTA is called in media query (`@media screen and (max-width: 550px) {`) to left align the table.

```html
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"><meta name="x-apple-disable-message-reformatting"><meta name="color-scheme" content="light dark"><meta name="supported-color-schemes" content="light dark"><!--[if !mso]><!--><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"><!--<![endif]--><title>%%=v(@preheader)=%%</title><!--[if mso]>
  <style type="text/css">
    table {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;margin:0;}
    div, td {padding:0;}
    div {margin:0 !important;}
    sup {font-size: 100% !important;}
  </style>
  <noscript>
    <xml>
      <o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
        <o:PixelsPerInch>96</o:PixelsPerInch>
    </xml>
  </noscript>
<![endif]--><!--[if gte mso 15]>
  <style type="text/css" media="all">
    /* Outlook 2013 Height Fix */
    table, tr, td {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0; }
a{ text-decoration: none !important;}
.em_hide_desktop {
                    display: none !important;
}
  </style>
<![endif]-->
<style type="text/css" >/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
      v2.0 | 20110126
      License: none (public domain)
      */
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details, embed, figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary, time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
.pcr {font-size:16px !important; line-height:24px !important; color:#333333; font-family:'PT Sans', 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif, Helvetica, 'Arial', sans-serif;font-weight: normal;margin:0px 0px 15px 0px !important; }
  t {font-size:16px !important; line-height:24px !important; color:#333333; font-family:'PT Sans', 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif, Helvetica, 'Arial', sans-serif;font-weight: normal;margin:0px 0px 15px 0px !important; }
.em_hide_desktop {
                    display: none !important;
}



ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after, q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}</style>
 <style type="text/css" >/* CLIENT-SPECIFIC STYLES */
img {
    -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
}
/* Force IE to smoothly render resized images. */
#outlook a {
    padding: 0;
}
/* Remove spacing between tables in Outlook 2007 and up. */
.ReadMsgBody {
    width: 100%;
}
.ExternalClass {
    width: 100%;
}
/* Force Outlook.com to display emails at full width. */
p, a, td {
    mso-line-height-rule: exactly;
}
/* Force Outlook to render line heights as they're originally set. */
p, a, td, body, table {
    -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}
/* Prevent Windows- and Webkit-based mobile platforms from changing declared text sizes. */
.ExternalClass, .ExternalClass p, .ExternalClass td, .ExternalClass div, .ExternalClass span, .ExternalClass font {
    line-height: 100%;
}
#MessageViewBody a {
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: inherit;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-weight: inherit;
    line-height: inherit;
}
/* Force Outlook.com to display line heights normally. */
a[x-apple-data-detectors] {
    color: inherit !important;
    text-decoration: none !important;
    font-size: inherit !important;
    font-family: inherit !important;
    font-weight: inherit !important;
    line-height: inherit !important;
}
span.MsoHyperlink {
    mso-style-priority: 99;
    color: inherit;
}
span.MsoHyperlinkFollowed {
    mso-style-priority: 99;
    color: inherit;
}</style>
 <style type="text/css" >@media screen and (max-width: 460px) {
.deviceWidth {
    width: 100%!important;
    min-width: 100%!important;
}
.em_main_table {
    width: 100% !important;
}
.em_wrapper {
    width: 100% !important;
}
  
.center {
    text-align: center !important;
    display: block !important;
}
.right {
    text-align: right !important;
    padding-right:20px;
}
.em_hide_desktop {
                    display: block !important;
}
.em_hide {
                    display: none !important;
}
}</style>
 <style type="text/css" >@media screen and (max-width: 350px) {
.three-col .column {
    max-width: 100% !important;
}
.two-col .column {
    max-width: 100% !important;
}
}

@media screen and (min-width: 351px) and (max-width: 460px) {
/* .three-col .column {
    max-width: 50% !important;
}
.three-col .column, .column1 {
    max-width: 100% !important;
    display: block !important;
} */
.five-col .column {
    max-width: 20% !important;
}
.six-col .column {
    max-width: 16% !important;
}
 
#em_hide_desktop {
                    display: block !important;
}
#em_hide {
                    display: none !important;
}
}

@media screen and (min-width: 461px) {
.three-col .column {
    max-width: 30% !important;
}
.three-col .column1 {
    max-width: 20% !important;
}
.two-col .column {
    max-width: 50% !important;
}
.five-col .column {
    max-width: 20% !important;
}
.sidebar .small {
    max-width: 16% !important;
}
.sidebar .large {
    max-width: 84% !important;
}
 
#em_hide_desktop {
                    display: block !important;
}
#em_hide {
                    display: none !important;
}
}

@media screen and (max-width: 550px) {
.three-col .column, .column1 {
    max-width: 100% !important;
    display: block !important;
}
.two-col .column, .two-col img {
    max-width: 100% !important;
    display: block !important;
}
.five-col .column {
    max-width: 33.3% !important;
}
.sidebar .small {
    max-width: 100% !important;
}
.sidebar .large {
    max-width: 100% !important;
}
 
#em_hide_desktop {
                    display: block !important;
}
#em_hide {
                    display: none !important;
}
.CTA{float:left !important;}
}</style>
 <style type="text/css" >@font-face {
    font-family: 'PT Sans';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/ptsans/v12/jizaRExUiTo99u79D0-ExcOPIDUg-g.woff2) format('woff2');
unicode-range: U+0460-052F, U+1C80-1C88, U+20B4, U+2DE0-2DFF, U+A640-A69F, U+FE2E-FE2F;
}</style>
 <style type="text/css" >@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
.dark-img {
    display: block !important;
    width: auto !important;
    overflow: visible !important;
    float: none !important;
    max-height: inherit !important;
    max-width: inherit !important;
    line-height: auto !important;
    margin-top: 0px !important;
    visibility: inherit !important;
}
.light-img {
    display: none !important;
}
.link-arrow-lm {
    display: none !important;
}
.link-arrow-dm {
    display: inline !important;
}
.darkmode {
    background-color: #161615 !important;
}
.darkmode-light-bg {
    background-color: #ffffff !important;
}
h1, h2, h3, h4 {
    color: #4F5948 !important;
}
h3, h4 {
    color: #c7102d !important;
}
h3, h4 {
    color: #c7102d !important;
}
p {
    color: #4F5948 !important;
}
a {
    color: #ffffff !important;
}
.light {
    color: #ffffff !important;
}
.dark {
    color: #4F5948 !important;
}
.blue {
    color: #005B9E !important;
}
.orange {
    color: #FF6000 !important;
}
[data-ogsc] .dark-img {
    display: block !important;
    width: auto !important;
    overflow: visible !important;
    float: none !important;
    max-height: inherit !important;
    max-width: inherit !important;
    line-height: auto !important;
    margin-top: 0px !important;
    visibility: inherit !important;
}
[data-ogsc] .light-img {
    display: none !important;
}
[data-ogsc] .link-arrow-lm {
    display: none !important;
}
[data-ogsc] .link-arrow-dm {
    display: inline !important;
}
[data-ogsc] .darkmode {
    background-color: #161615 !important;
}
[data-ogsc] .darkmode-light-bg {
    background-color: #ffffff !important;
}
[data-ogsc] h1, [data-ogsc] h2 {
    color: #4F5948 !important;
}
[data-ogsc] h3, [data-ogsc] h4 {
    color: #c7102d !important;
}
[data-ogsc] p {
    color: #4F5948 !important;
}
[data-ogsc] a {
    color: #ffffff !important;
}
[data-ogsc] .light {
    color: #ffffff !important;
}
[data-ogsc] .dark {
    color: #4F5948 !important;
}
[data-ogsc] .blue {
    color: #005B9E !important;
}
[data-ogsc] .orange {
    color: #FF6000 !important;
}
}</style>
</head>
<body>

<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="border-collapse: collapse; padding: 0; margin: 0; width:100%;" width="100%">
          <tbody>
           <tr>
            <td align="left" style="border-top:3px solid #FF6000;"><a alias="Hero image" href="%%MBPDEEPLINKCHOOSEYOURSEATS%%?utm_source=mc-transactional&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=bcn-destination-upsell&utm_content=select-room-img&utm_term=en&ajs_event=Email%20Link%20Clicked&ajs_uid=%%SubscriberKey%%" style="text-decoration:none; color:#ffffff; font-family:'PT Sans','Lucida Grande', Helvetica, Arial,sans-serif; font-size: 14px; line-height: 26px; font-weight: normal; text-align:center;" target="_blank"><img alt="Two women entering a hotel room" border="0" src="https://assets.sunwingtravelgroup.com/image/upload/v1641915021/sunwing-prod/Email/Sunwing/BCN/images/SelectRoom_02.png" style="border: 0; display: block; font-family:'PT Sans','Lucida Grande', Helvetica, Arial,sans-serif; font-size: 14px; height: auto; max-width: 600px; outline: 0; padding: 0; width: 100%; display: block;" width="660"></a></td>
           </tr>
          </tbody>
         </table>

         <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="border-collapse: collapse; padding: 0; margin: 0; width:100%;" width="100%">
          <tbody>
           <tr>
            <td align="left" style="padding: 0 26px;">
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="border-collapse: collapse; padding: 0; margin: 0; width:100%;" width="100%">
             <tbody>
              <tr>
               <td align="left" style="padding: 20px 0 10px;">
               <p class="light" style="color:#595959; font-family:'PT Sans','Lucida Grande', Helvetica, Arial,sans-serif; font-weight:bold; font-size:25px; line-height:30px; margin:0;"><span style="font-weight: bold;">Pick the perfect spot</span></p>
               </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
               <td align="left" style="padding: 5px 0 0;">
               <p class="light" style="color:#595959; font-family:'PT Sans','Lucida Grande', Helvetica, Arial,sans-serif; font-weight:normal; font-size:14px; line-height:20px; margin:0;">
Want to be closest to the beach or steps from the pool? Choose your room location prior to arrival.
</p>
               </td>
              </tr>
             <tr>
               <td align="left"  style="padding: 30px 0;align:left !important"><!-- CTA BUTTON -->
               <table class="CTA" bgcolor="#005B9E" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="border: none; border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; mso-table-lspace: 0; mso-table-rspace: 0; background-color:#005B9E; min-width: 180px;">
                <tbody>
                 <tr>
                  <td align="left" style="border-collapse:collapse; font-family:'PT Sans','Lucida Grande', Helvetica, Arial,sans-serif; font-size: 14px; line-height: 18px; font-weight: normal; padding:0; border: 0; text-align:center; color:#ffffff; mso-padding-alt:12px 26px; vertical-align: middle;"><a alias="Start planning-CTA" class="light" href="%%MBPDEEPLINKVACATIONCHECKLIST%%?utm_source=mc-transactional&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=bcn-destination-upsell&utm_content=select-room-cta&utm_term=en" style="text-decoration:none; color:#ffffff; font-family:'PT Sans','Lucida Grande', Helvetica, Arial,sans-serif; font-size: 14px; line-height: 26px; font-weight: normal; text-align:center;" target="_blank"><!--[if !gte mso 9]><!----><span style="padding:12px 26px; display:block;align:left"><!--<![endif]-->Select your room <!--[if !gte mso 9]><!----> </span><!--<![endif]--> </a></td>
                 </tr>
                </tbody>
               </table>
               </td>
               <!-- /CTA BUTTON -->
              </tr>
             </tbody>
            </table>
            </td>
           </tr>
          </tbody>
         </table>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried this but unfortunately it doesn't solve the issue. In outlook mobile, the CTA is still centered where I want it left aligned like the rest of the clients.

Comment: @ArchanaSelvakumaran Which outlook are you using for mobile view?

Comment: Outlook version 4.2 in my iPhone 11 pro max. I tested in some of my other collegue's devices and outlook in all versions it is centered.

Comment: I have floated it left using CSS. Let me know if its left now.

Comment: oh it did.. Thanks a lot. I have been ramming my brains this whole week for this issue. Fairly new to HTML/CSS and this is the first time I am using float. LOL. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

`align="left"` attribute applied to a table cell aligns its content. If it's applied to a table, it aligns the table itself.

I see these things that probably affect on aligning of the button you want to center:

- you use `align="left"` on 2 `td` and 1 `table` surrounding the link of the button
- there's `padding-right="400"` attribute that does not exist and probably breaks your desired layout
- `align:left !important` in a style attribute on the cell containing the button code

Comment: Yep please try this Archana and see how you go, email clients have a habit of removing entire inline styles or style blocks if there's an error in one part of it.

Comment: That didn’t help. I tried putting align !important in the style attribute and removing the padding-right.. just not happening

Comment: Have you already tried to change a value of the align attribute to center for those td and table associated with the button?

Comment: And what about `align important!` you mention above: are you assigning it like `style="text-align: center !important"`? Check the declaration for syntax errors

Comment: Yes I tried centering that align value and even removing it. Didn't work and also tried align !important. Nothing worked.